# BSOD With Audio

Tags: audio, bsod, event-viewer

I'm keep getting a BSOD, and if there's any audio playing, a loud pulsating sound comes out of the speakers (during the BSOD). I think it's probably like last half a second or so of the audio that I was listening to, but could that indicate what's causing the BSOD, or is that just normal? I know it's not the RAM, my current guess is that it's the GPU. The error in Event Viewer is always "Kernel-Power," but it just says that that's caused by the computer shutting down unexpectedly (which I assume is when I hit the restart button on my computer after the BSOD occurs...) A warning occurred at the same time last time, named "Kernel-EventTracing." That error says the the Microsoft Security Client OOBE stopped, error 0xC000000D.

Thanks.

EDIT: From what I remember, I think the BSOD almost always happens while I'm watching video/listening to audio, but that could be because I do that almost constantly. It also happens sometimes if I'm playing a game (non in-particular).

Comment: If it happens when playing audio/video (both of which use the sound card), try updating/reinstalling your sound card drivers

Comment: The sound sticking could be just due to the kernel crashing while that data is active in the sound adapter.  Updating drivers is a good idea, but you also want to ensure the system isn't overheating (video playback can be pretty hardware-intensive, causing heat).  Have you ensured all system fans and heat-sinks are clean, attached properly and working?

Comment: Yes, it all seems to be working fine. There are around 12 fans in my case, and it doesn't always happen when doing something too intensive (like gaming), it mostly happens just when watching a video stream or something.

Comment: @techie007 sticking sounds happens whenever the kernel crashes, if sound is being played at the time. However, `@`Rev says that this happens whenever he is doing something that utilizes the sound card